# Onclick with Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this two buttons:

```
<button onclick="filterSelection('Action')">Action</button>
```

and

```
<button onclick="filterSelection('Adventure')">Adventure</button>
```

Now, I want to do the same but with Vue.JS, so I created this array on my app.js

```
genres: [{name: 'Action'}, {name:'Adventure'}]
```

And in my HTML file:

```
<button v-for="genre of genres">{{genre.name}}</button>
```

That's works fine, but I don't know how to add the propertie with Vue.JS:

```
onclick="filterSelection('genre')"
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having the attribute `v-on:click="filterSelection(genre)"` on your button.

Edit: Forgot quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Since vue uses a virtual dom, you cannot use the "native html" events.

Instead you define click events via an event handler  [[docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)]

```
<div id="example-1">
  <button v-on:click="counter += 1">
    Add 1
  </button>
  <p>
    The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.
  </p>
</div>
```

alternatively you can use the shorthand for `v-on` and use the `@` symbol like `@click=`